# What is the name of this inequality? (Lower bound for polynomials in $\mathbb{C}$)

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm trying to find a upper bound for a integral involving a polynomial a found this in a book but I need more information about it. And the book does not mention the name.
Does anyone know? 
$$\dfrac{1}{|P(z)|}<\dfrac{2}{|a_n|K^n}$$

Edit: 
$P$ is a polynomial of degree $n$, $a_n$ is the leading coefficient, and $K$ is a real number.

More precisely, I saw it in this paper (page 22 of the pdf) https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/f460/35cf351f474f6ee3ca41c23fb214c62a56eb.pdf

I know it is named after a mathematician. But I lost my notes where I had that info.

Comment: What is $K$? I guess $a_n$ is the leading coefficient and $n$ is the degree of $P$ Is that correct?

Comment: Please state the problem more precisely. Where does the inequality hold? What is $K?$

Comment: Read the statement in previous page (page 21 in pdf = page 13 in article),
"There exists $\color{red}{\text{large enough}}$ $K \in N$ such that when $|z| \ge K$, $\frac{|a_i|}{|z^{n-i}|} < \frac{|a_n|}{2n}$". This is not any named inequality....

Comment: @achillehui It seems that my memory is failing :c